# Shell script not working at startup even it add in /etc/rc.local

Tags: shell, ubuntu

My shell script not working at startup even it add in /etc/rc.local.
It is also a excutable shell .
Put my script in start up like this

```
ash!/bin/sh -e
sh 'home/project/myscript.sh'
exit 0
```

But it is worked in sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start

Comment: Your user has the permission to run it?

Comment: Have you set the execution of `rc.local`?  This file is typically installed without the execution and is only enabled by setting it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/239600/why-doesnt-rc-local-run-all-my-commands-and-what-can-i-do-about-it

Comment: yes ,it is worked in /etc/init.d/rc.local start

Comment: i set chmod +x /etc/rc.local,but no progress  .My  permision like this ls -l /etc/rc.local    -rwxrwxr-x 1 root eyenet 63 2014-03-26 12:19 /etc/rc.local

Comment: `ash` -> `#`, or is that a typo in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding ...

```
ash!/bin/sh -e
```

This is not a valid shebang/hashbang and should probably be

```
#!/bin/sh -e
```

Regarding ...

```
sh 'home/project/myscript.sh'
```

1. Use an absolute path to `myscript.sh`
2. If this file has a proper shebang like above you don't need the `sh`, just call it like

   ```
   /foo/bar/home/project/myscript.sh
   ```

Regarding ...

```
exit 0
```

This is superfluous/implicit and thus not needed, you can remove it.

Comment: ok script runs successfully,,but i have another problem my script contains "python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.25:1033".During the script run from startup this is not working but  "python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.0:8000" working successfully

Comment: Same problem, it probably cannot find `manage.py`. You need to use absolute paths.

Comment: iam using cd home/project.No problem on manage.py .How to set externel ip like 192.168.1.25:1033 on shell script to start django on startup? With local ip like "127.0.0.0:8000 " works fine but 192.168.1.25:1033 not works .I think problem is in ip setting